# Load Jest types from "@jest/globals" globally

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Is it possible to load the types from "**@jest/globals**" globally in Jest with TypeScript?
According to the documentation, you can make the following import per test file. This also gives you TypeScript support:

```
import {expect, jest, test} from '@jest/globals';
```

I would like to do this globally in just one file and not in each individual test file. I know that there is also "**@types/jest**". But unfortunately the type definitions for e.g. "**jest.fn**" differ. Therefore this package is out of the question for me.

Example of the "**jest.fn**" type difference:

from "**@types/jest**" (current version: v29.5.10):

```js
// Type definition: export function jest.fn(): jest.Mock<any, any, any>
const mock = jest.fn<MyType>(); // <- This doesn't work ❌

>> TS2743: No overload expects  1  type arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either  0  or  2  type arguments.
```

from "**@jest/globals**" (current version: v29.7.0):

```js
// Type definition: Jest.fn: <T=UnknownFunction extends FunctionLike>(implementation?: (T | undefined)) => Mock<T>
const mock = jest.fn<MyType>(); // <- This works ✅
```